# How to prevent python from inserting duplicates into mongodb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, duplicates, insert-update

I have json data stored in a variable that gets inserted into a MongoDB, once per day with Python. But the json data in the variable often does not change, but it still get's inserted into the MongoDB ... which creates masses of duplicates of the same entries.

Every entry in the json data variable each has 1 unique key: `uuid`.

---

How do you prevent Python from inserting duplicates into MongoDB? I looked into `db.collection.update()`, but I'm not sure if its suitable and I don't know how to use it with a variable?

Comment: I don't know no-sql databases but in SQL databases you may have command `UPDATE OR INSERT`. You can also first check if element exist in database and don't add it if already exists.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can check its id for uniqueness, you can use the method **update_one()** and set **upsert** for that.

For example,

```
filter_data = {'uuid': '111'}
new_data = {'$set': {'new_value': 25}} 
db.collection.update_one(filter_data, new_data, upsert=True)
```

This will check if **uuid = '111'** exists, if not it will create a document; otherwise, update it.